# Extra restrictions in best response functions using Manipulate[ ]?

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate, parametric-functions

I have two best response functions that I have defined like this:

```
BRc[p_, s_, l_] := (3 p + 2 s + 4 l p s + 4 l s^2)/(4 (1 + 2 l s));
BRp[c_, s_, l_] := (-(c/s) - c/(s (2 + 4 l s)))/(
  1/(2 (1 + 2 l s)^2) - 2/(1 + 2 l s) - 2/(s (1 + 2 l s)));
```

I want to define certain ranges, values and add a title for the plot, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{p, BRc[p, s, l]}, {BRp[c, s, l], c}}, {c, 0, 
   50}, {p, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 50}}, AxesLabel -> {c, p}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Best Response Curves", Blue, 20]], 
 Style["Parameters", Bold, Medium], {s, 0, 10}, {l, 0, 10}]
```

But I need to define the following restrictions inside `Manipulate[ ]`:

```
p > 0 && ((0 < l < 1/
      2 && ((p < c < p/(2 l) && 
         0 < s < (-2 c + p)/(4 c l - 2 p)) || (c >= p/(2 l) && 
         s > 0))) || (1/2 <= l <= 1 && c > p && s > 0))
```

To make sure that the two functions always intersect.

**I don't know where to insert the restrictions. Help needed here. Also I would like to name the axis**

When I run the code without these restrictions, I get the following image/error:

[image]

Comment: You can try [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) instead of `AxesLabel`.

Comment: @Karsten7. `FrameLabel` worked. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not confident that the restrictions

```
p > 0 && c > 
  p && ((0 < l < p/(2 c) && 
     0 < s < (-2 c + p)/(4 c l - 2 p)) || (p/(2 c) <= l <= 1 && 
     s > 0))
```

will ensure that the two functions will intersect.

However to answer the question about how to implement these restrictions in `Manipulate` we will redefine the two functions so that each have all four of the variables `c`, `p`, `s` and `l`.

Further we will apply the restriction to the definition of the functions:

```
BRc[p_, s_, l_, c_] := (3 p + 2 s + 4 l p s + 4 l s^2)/(4 (1 + 2 l s)) /; 
  p > 0 && c > 
    p && ((0 < l < p/(2 c) && 
       0 < s < (-2 c + p)/(4 c l - 2 p)) || (p/(2 c) <= l <= 1 && 
       s > 0))

BRp[c_, s_, l_, p_] := (-(c/s) - c/(s (2 + 4 l s)))/(1/(2 (1 + 2 l s)^2) - 
     2/(1 + 2 l s) - 2/(s (1 + 2 l s))) /; 
  p > 0 && c > 
    p && ((0 < l < p/(2 c) && 
       0 < s < (-2 c + p)/(4 c l - 2 p)) || (p/(2 c) <= l <= 1 && 
       s > 0))
```

Now the `Manipulate` can be used (it is a bit slow). I found that `l` had to be greater than zero and less than 1 in order for the restriction to be satisfied.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{p, BRc[p, s, l, c]}, {BRp[c, s, l, p], c}}, {c, 0, 
   50}, {p, 0, 50},
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 50}},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Best Response Curves", Blue, 20]
  ],

 {{s, 1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{l, 0.001}, 0.001, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I was not able to get `AxesLabel` to work. My workaround would be to manually label with with text or see if you can find a solution on this site.

Comment: Jack, thx for input! l<1 means that they always intersect? I fixed the labeling using `FrameLabel`  - suggestion from @Karsten7 above.